# I always get a "scan and fix" message for external HDD, but no problem ever found (Win 7)

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, diagnostic, scan-disk

I have an external HDD that, when I plug it into my Windows 7 laptop, always initializes with the "do you want to scan and fix" message.  I've run it a few times, but the built in Windows scanner never finds any problems.  Additionally, the "access" light on the HDD is almost always on when I have it plugged into the computer, and I can never get Windows to "safely remove" the hard drive.  I've never had any issues reading or writing to the HDD.

So, what tools are out there to better diagnose and fix this issue? Or is it not a real issue with the HDD?  I was thinking of backing up and reformatting, but I'd like to try some other diagnostics first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try scanning this drive in other program (hd tune, hdd regenerator) it could have bad sectors.

Many programs access files in ext drives for a long period of time so they're "always" unsafe to remove. I recomend using USB EJECTOR for safely removing usb devices - it's much better than windows explorer.

Answer (score 2):

The "scan and fix" is usually caused by unplugging the external drive without safely removing it. The reason you cannot safely remove it might be that Windows 7 is indexing the content of the drive for searching or that a virus scanner is reading the drive.

Comment: Thats true either.